# Find all values by specific key in a deep nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, ecmascript-6

How would I find all values by specific key in a deep nested object?

For example, if I have an object like this:

```
const myObj = {
  id: 1,
  children: [
    {
      id: 2,
      children: [
        {
          id: 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      children: [
        {
          id: 5,
          children: [
            {
              id: 6,
              children: [
                {
                  id: 7,
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

How would I get an array of all values throughout all nests of this obj by the key of `id`.

Note: `children` is a consistent name, and `id`'s won't exist outside of a `children` object.

So from the obj, I would like to produce an array like this:

```
const idArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could make a recursive function like this:

```js
idArray = []

function func(obj) {
  idArray.push(obj.id)
  if (!obj.children) {
    return
  }

  obj.children.forEach(child => func(child))
}
```

Snippet for your sample:

```js
const myObj = {
  id: 1,
  children: [{
      id: 2,
      children: [{
        id: 3
      }]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      children: [{
        id: 5,
        children: [{
          id: 6,
          children: [{
            id: 7,
          }]
        }]
      }]
    },
  ]
}

idArray = []

function func(obj) {
  idArray.push(obj.id)
  if (!obj.children) {
    return
  }

  obj.children.forEach(child => func(child))
}

func(myObj)
console.log(idArray)
```

Answer (score 32):

This is a bit late but for anyone else finding this, here is a clean, generic recursive function:

```
function findAllByKey(obj, keyToFind) {
  return Object.entries(obj)
    .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => (key === keyToFind)
      ? acc.concat(value)
      : (typeof value === 'object')
      ? acc.concat(findAllByKey(value, keyToFind))
      : acc
    , [])
}

// USAGE
findAllByKey(myObj, 'id')
```

Comment: super clean, works well, easy cut & paste. Best answer.

Comment: This saved me a bit of time and is fun to consider to boot.  Thank you!

Comment: Changed line 5 to `: (typeof value === 'object' && value)` because for some reason, `typeof null === "object"`.

Comment: Best solution so far, thanks a ton Steve

Comment: What would the type-safe version of this function look like?

Answer (score 9):

I found steve's answer to be most suited for my needs in extrapolating this out and creating a general recursive function. That said, I encountered issues when dealing with nulls and undefined values, so I extended the condition to accommodate for this. This approach uses:

[Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) - It uses an accumulator function which appends the value's onto the result array. It also splits each object into it's key:value pair which allows you to take the following steps:

1. Have you've found the key? If so, add it to the array;
2. If not, have I found an object with values? If so, the key is possibly within there. Keep digging by calling the function on this object and append the result onto the result array; and
3. Finally, if this is not an object, return the result array unchanged.

Hope it helps!

```js
const myObj = {
  id: 1,
  children: [{
      id: 2,
      children: [{
        id: 3
      }]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      children: [{
        id: 5,
        children: [{
          id: 6,
          children: [{
            id: 7,
          }]
        }]
      }]
    },
  ]
}

function findAllByKey(obj, keyToFind) {
  return Object.entries(obj)
    .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => (key === keyToFind)
      ? acc.concat(value)
      : (typeof value === 'object' && value)
      ? acc.concat(findAllByKey(value, keyToFind))
      : acc
    , []) || [];
}

const ids = findAllByKey(myObj, 'id');

console.log(ids)
```

Comment: InternalError: too much recursion

Comment: Have you got an example object?

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what i needed! Works great.

Answer (score 6):

You can make a generic recursive function that works with any property and any object.

This uses [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray), [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

The stopping condition is when the object passed in is empty:

```js
const myObj = {
  id: 1,
  anyProp: [{
    id: 2,
    thing: { a: 1, id: 10 },
    children: [{ id: 3 }]
  }, {
    id: 4,
    children: [{
      id: 5,
      children: [{
        id: 6,
        children: [{ id: 7 }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

const getValues = prop => obj => {
  if (!Object.keys(obj).length) { return []; }

  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
    if (key === prop) {
      acc.push(val);
    } else {
      acc.push(Array.isArray(val) ? val.map(getIds).flat() : getIds(val));
    }
    return acc.flat();
  }, []);
}

const getIds = getValues('id');

console.log(getIds(myObj));
```

Answer (score 6):

> Note: `children` is a consistent name, and `id`'s wont exist outside
>   of a `children` object.
>
> So from the obj, I would like to produce an array like this:
>
> ```
> const idArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
> ```

Given that the question does not contain any restrictions on how the output is derived from the input and that the input is consistent, where the value of property `"id"` is a digit and `id` property is defined only within `"children"` property, save for case of the first `"id"` in the object, the input JavaScript plain object can be converted to a `JSON` string using `JSON.stringify()`, `RegExp` `/"id":\d+/g` matches the `"id"` property and one or more digit characters following the property name, which is then mapped to `.match()` the digit portion of the previous match using `Regexp` `\d+` and convert the array value to a JavaScript number using addition operator `+`

```js
const myObject = {"id":1,"children":[{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3}]},{"id":4,"children":[{"id":5,"children":[{"id":6,"children":[{"id":7}]}]}]}]};

let res = JSON.stringify(myObject).match(/"id":\d+/g).map(m => +m.match(/\d+/));

console.log(res);
```

`JSON.stringify()` `replacer` function can alternatively be used to `.push()` the value of every `"id"` property name within the object to an array

```js
const myObject = {"id":1,"children":[{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3}]},{"id":4,"children":[{"id":5,"children":[{"id":6,"children":[{"id":7}]}]}]}]};

const getPropValues = (o, prop) => 
  (res => (JSON.stringify(o, (key, value) => 
    (key === prop && res.push(value), value)), res))([]);

let res = getPropValues(myObject, "id");

console.log(res);
```

Since the property values of the input to be matched are digits, all the JavaScript object can be converted to a string and `RegExp` `\D` can be used to replace all characters that are not digits, spread resulting string to array, and `.map()` digits to JavaScript numbers

```
let res = [...JSON.stringify(myObj).replace(/\D/g,"")].map(Number)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using recursion.

```js
const myObj = {  id: 1,  children: [    {      id: 2,      children: [        {          id: 3        }      ]    },    {      id: 4,      children: [        {          id: 5,          children: [            {              id: 6,              children: [                {                  id: 7,                }              ]            }          ]        }      ]    },  ]},
    loop = (array, key, obj) => {
      if (!obj.children) return;
      obj.children.forEach(c => {
        if (c[key]) array.push(c[key]); // is not present, skip!
        loop(array, key, c);
      });
    },
    arr = myObj["id"] ? [myObj["id"]] : [];
    
loop(arr, "id", myObj);
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a recursive function with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) like so:

```js
const myObj = {
  id: 1,
  children: [{
      id: 2,
      children: [{
        id: 3
      }]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      children: [{
        id: 5,
        children: [{
          id: 6,
          children: [{
            id: 7,
          }]
        }]
      }]
    },
  ]
};

function findIds(obj) {
  const entries = Object.entries(obj);
  let result = entries.map(e => {
    if (e[0] == "children") {
      return e[1].map(child => findIds(child));
    } else {
      return e[1];
    }
  });
  function flatten(arr, flat = []) {
    for (let i = 0, length = arr.length; i < length; i++) {
      const value = arr[i];
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        flatten(value, flat);
      } else {
        flat.push(value);
      }
    }
    return flat;
  }
  return flatten(result);
}

var ids = findIds(myObj);
console.log(ids);
```

Flattening function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39000004/10221765)

ES5 syntax:

```js
var myObj = {
  id: 1,
  children: [{
      id: 2,
      children: [{
        id: 3
      }]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      children: [{
        id: 5,
        children: [{
          id: 6,
          children: [{
            id: 7,
          }]
        }]
      }]
    },
  ]
};

function findIds(obj) {
  const entries = Object.entries(obj);
  let result = entries.map(function(e) {
    if (e[0] == "children") {
      return e[1].map(function(child) {
        return findIds(child)
      });
    } else {
      return e[1];
    }
  });
  function flatten(arr, flat = []) {
    for (let i = 0, length = arr.length; i < length; i++) {
      const value = arr[i];
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        flatten(value, flat);
      } else {
        flat.push(value);
      }
    }
    return flat;
  }
  return flatten(result);
}

var ids = findIds(myObj);
console.log(ids);
```

Comment: No problem @cup_of, I'm glad to help

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = JSON.stringify(myObj);
let array = str.match(/\d+/g).map(v => v * 1);
console.log(array); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for a lot of our data processing needs now. It makes the code much more maintainable, but does take a moment to wrap your head around. Here is how you could use it to answer your question

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const find = (data, needle) => objectScan([needle], { rtn: 'value' })(data);

const myObj = { id: 1, children: [{ id: 2, children: [ { id: 3 } ] }, { id: 4, children: [ { id: 5, children: [ { id: 6, children: [ { id: 7 } ] } ] } ] }] };

console.log(find(myObj, '**.id'));
// => [ 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score 0):

```
import {flattenDeep} from 'lodash';

/**
 * Extracts all values from an object (also nested objects)
 * into a single array
 *
 * @param obj
 * @returns
 *
 * @example
 * const test = {
 *  alpha: 'foo',
 *  beta: {
 *    gamma: 'bar',
 *    lambda: 'baz'
 *  }
 * }
 *
 * objectFlatten(test) // ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
 */
export function objectFlatten(obj: {}) {
  const result = [];
  for (const prop in obj) {
    const value = obj[prop];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      result.push(objectFlatten(value));
    } else {
      result.push(value);
    }
  }
  return flattenDeep(result);
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you write an explanation on what you example code does.

Comment: @chrwahl please see the jsdocs comment above code it even comes with examples.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution is generic which will return all values by matching nested keys as well e.g for below json object

```
{
   "a":1,
   "b":{
      "a":{
         "a":"red"
      }
   },
   "c":{
      "d":2
   }
}
```

to find all values matching key "a" output should be return

```
[1,{a:"red"},"red"]
```

```
const findkey = (obj, key) => {
  let arr = [];
  if (isPrimitive(obj)) return obj;

  for (let [k, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (k === key) arr.push(val);
    if (!isPrimitive(val)) arr = [...arr, ...findkey(val, key)];
  }
  return arr;
};

const isPrimitive = (val) => {
  return val !== Object(val);
};
```