# NodeJS - flatten nested array in recursion into an array of strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, recursion

I have this datas structure:

```
{
  "fieldNodes": [
    {
      "selectionSet": {
        "selections": [
          {
            "name": {
              "value": "id"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": {
              "value": "phone"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": {
              "value": "address"
            },
            "selectionSet": {
              "selections": [
                {
                  "name": {
                    "value": "street"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "name": {
                    "value": "city"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to go over the `fieldNodes` array in recursion and create an array of strings of their value (`name.value`).

The nested values will be represented by a dot (`"address.city"`).

The results for this example will be: `["id", "phone", "address. street", "address.city"]`.

I'm assuming that I have one object in the `fieldNodes` array.

Can someone please help me how the code should look like in NodeJS?

Comment: I try the solution from this and it works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54857222/find-all-values-by-specific-key-in-a-deep-nested-object

Answer (score 1):

Once you descend to the `selectionSort` level, it's a fairly straightforward recursion.  Here we wrap that recursive call into one that (`flat`)`maps` over the `fieldNodes` objects.  Since you expect only one, it doesn't matter whether we `map` or `flatMap` here, and this result is simpler.  But if you might have more than one, and you want them grouped, you might replace `fieldNodes .flatMap (...)` with `fieldNodes .map (...)`

```js
const processSelectionSet = ({selectionSet: {selections = []}}) =>
  selections.flatMap (
    ({name: {value}, selectionSet}) => selectionSet 
      ? processSelectionSet ({selectionSet}) .map (name => `${value}.${name}`)
      : value
  )

const extract = ({fieldNodes = []}) => 
  fieldNodes .flatMap (processSelectionSet)

const input = {fieldNodes: [{selectionSet: {selections: [{name: {value: "id"}}, {name: {value: "phone"}}, {name: {value: "address"}, selectionSet: {selections: [{name: {value: "street"}}, {name: {value: "city"}}]}}]}}]}

console .log (extract (input))
```

The main function, `processSelectionSort` simply flatmaps over the `selections`, capturing the name/value reporting it back if there is no `selectionSort` child node or merging it with the results of the recursive call to that child node if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this recursive function that I made:

```js
var obj = {
  "fieldNodes": [{
    "selectionSet": {
      "selections": [{
          "name": {
            "value": "id"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": {
            "value": "phone"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": {
            "value": "address"
          },
          "selectionSet": {
            "selections": [{
                "name": {
                  "value": "street"
                }
              },
              {
                "name": {
                  "value": "city"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }]
};

function flatten(obj) {
  if (!obj.selectionSet) {
    if (obj.name) return [obj.name.value];
    return [];
  }
    
  var list = obj.selectionSet.selections.map(flatten).flat();
  if (!obj.name) return list;
  return list.map(item => obj.name.value + "." + item);
}

var list = obj.fieldNodes.map(flatten).flat();
console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```js
var data = {'fieldNodes': [{'selectionSet': {'selections': [{'name': {'value': 'id'}}, {'name': {'value': 'phone'}}, {'name': {'value': 'address'}, 'selectionSet': {'selections': [{'name': {'value': 'street'}}, {'name': {'value': 'city'}}]}}]}}]}
function* flatten(d, c = []){
    for (var i of d){
       if ("selectionSet" in i){
           yield* flatten(i.selectionSet.selections, 'name' in i ? [...c, i.name.value] : c)
       }
       else{
          yield [...c, i.name.value]
       }
    }
}
var result = Array.from(flatten(data.fieldNodes)).map(x => x.join('.'));
console.log(result)
```