# Search a deeply nested array to update an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, lodash, underscore.js

I have a deeply nested data structure and I am interested in matching a certain value inside my array (and array of arrays) and then pushing some data inside an accompanying array. For example following is my array of **colors** and accompanied is a **moreColors** array which may or may not exist :

```
var myData = [{
    "color": "green",
    "moreColors": [
        {
            "color": "beige"
        },
        {
            "color": "black",
            "moreColor": [
                {
                    "color": "grey"
                },
                {
                    "color": "white",
                    "moreColors": [...]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

I am interested in searching my array for the color value **grey** and to that object adding a moreColors array `moreColors: [{"color" : "blue"}]` . In certain cases this might be using a **push()** method if the array already exists. How would I best achieve this? My goal here is that I want to add values and update/mutate **myData** array here because this will be passed on to another function. The nesting here can be several levels deep so a simple loop inside a loop won't work. Would a recursive function work best here? I am also open to better methods or using libraries like **underscore** or **lodash**. Although I'd prefer a vanilla js version. Below is a recursive solution I started however, the code won't run more than a level deep.

```
findNested(myData, "grey")

function findNested(myArray, color) {
    myArray.moreColors?.forEach(element => {
        if(element.color !== color){
            if(element.moreColors.length > 0) {
                findNested(element.moreColors, color);
            }
        } else {
                element.moreColors.push({
                    "color": "blue"
                });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all values by specific key in a deep nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54857222/find-all-values-by-specific-key-in-a-deep-nested-object)

Comment: @pilchard The question on that page looks for all the ids and creates a new array, however I want to update my already existing myData array. So something maybe like forEach would be preferable as it updates the current array with the object pushed inside.

Comment: What you do once you find the nested object is up to you and is straightforward, your primary question seemed to be about finding an arbitrarily deep object by key which the duplicate addresses (there are more duplicates if you search).

Comment: My question however is more geared towards specifically updating my current array because I will be passing this to another function.

Comment: Please share what you have attempted till now and what issue/s or error/s are faced. This may help other members to direct you towards a solution specific to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick example of what I think you are attempting.

`findNestedColorObject()` accepts an array of and a color string to search for and returns the first object whose `color` property matches.

`updateMoreColors()` accepts an object as returned from the above and first assigns `moreColors` if it doesn't exist, and then pushes to array.

```js
function findNestedColorObject(array, color) {
  let colorObject;

  for (const obj of array) {
    if (obj.color === color) {
      colorObject = obj;
    } else if (obj.moreColors !== undefined) {
      colorObject = findNestedColorObject(obj.moreColors, color);
    }

    if (colorObject !== undefined) {
      break;
    }
  }

  return colorObject;
}

function updateMoreColors(colorObject, colors) {
  colorObject.moreColors ??= [];
  
  for (const color of [].concat(colors)) {
    colorObject.moreColors.push({ color });
  }
}

const myData = [{ "color": "green", "moreColors": [{ "color": "beige" }, { "color": "black", "moreColors": [{ "color": "grey" }, { "color": "white", "moreColors": ["ochre"] }] }] }];

const greyObject = findNestedColorObject(myData, 'grey');
console.log('found:')
console.log(greyObject);

updateMoreColors(greyObject, 'purple');
console.log('updated:');
console.log(greyObject);

const beigeObject = findNestedColorObject(myData, 'beige');
console.log('found:')
console.log(beigeObject);

updateMoreColors(beigeObject, ['salmon', 'crimson']);
console.log('updated:');
console.log(beigeObject);

// edit per the commments
const data = [{ color: "beige", moreColors: [{ color: "blue" }] }, { color: "black", moreColors: [{ color: "white" }] }];
const blue = findNestedColorObject(data, 'blue');
console.log('fixed overwrite error:')
console.log(blue);
```

Or, since your attempt seems to search and update in the same function you can combine the two functions above. (This will continue to update all objects which match, not just the first).

```js
function updateNestedColorObject(array, color, moreColors) {
  for (const obj of array) {
    if (obj.color === color) {
      obj.moreColors ??= [];
      for (const color of [].concat(moreColors)) {
        obj.moreColors.push({ color });
      }
    }
    if (obj.moreColors !== undefined) {
      updateNestedColorObject(obj.moreColors, color, moreColors);
    }
  }
}

const myData = [{ "color": "green", "moreColors": [{ "color": "beige" }, { "color": "black", "moreColors": [{ "color": "grey" }, { "color": "white", "moreColors": ["ochre"] }] }] }];

updateNestedColorObject(myData, 'grey', 'purple');
updateNestedColorObject(myData, 'purple', 'beige');
updateNestedColorObject(myData, 'beige', ['salmon', 'crimson']);

console.log(myData);
```

#### Edit

As noted in the comments my first `findNestedColorObject` wasn't exiting the loop as it should on successful search. Quick fix applied though there is probably a cleaner solution.

Comment: Your `findNestedColorObject()` may override the correct search result by error. Try searching for `"blue"` with this data set: `[{ color: "beige", moreColors: [{ color: "blue" }] }, { color: "black", moreColors: [{ color: "white" }] }]`

Comment: @OskarGrosser good, catch. It wasn't exiting the loop on successful return. Quick fix applied, I'll look at it later to clean it up in general.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, there are depths to which I will not let myself sink.  I won't help you do something so barbaric as mutating your original data.

But if you're interested in a version that creates a new structure out of your old, with the additional color nodes in their proper place, we can write a reasonably simple recursion:

```js
const addColor = (target, newColor) => (xs) =>
  xs .map (({color, moreColors = []}) => ({
    color,  
    ... (color == target
      ? {moreColors: addColor (target, newColor) (moreColors) .concat ({color: newColor})}
      : moreColors .length > 0
        ? {moreColors: addColor (target, newColor) (moreColors)} 
        : {}
    )
  }))

const myData = [{color: "green", moreColors: [{color: "beige"}, {color: "black", moreColors: [{color: "grey"}, {color: "white", moreColors: [{color: "..."}]}]}]}]

console .log (addColor ('grey', 'blue') (myData))
// console .log (myData) // uncomment to see that the original has not been folded, spindled, or mutilated
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We map over the array, keeping the color property intact and then handling the `moreColors` in one of three ways:

- if the `color` matches our target color, we recur on the `moreColors` node, and append to it our additional color.  (If this node was missing, we've defaulted it to  an empty array.)
- if not, and we have existing `moreColor` entries, we recur on them
- and if we don't have any, we skip the `moreColor` node altogether.

Comment: My above array is not my original data though, its a deep copy. I am trying to avoid what is being suggested here which is to create a new array, and I am specifically interested in updating my current array.

Comment: I'm not surprised.  I just don't participate in such sketchy coding practices.  :-)  Best of luck.

Comment: I should have added that this is mostly snark.  Some of my best friends still mutate input data.  :-)  I simply prefer to work in as mutation-free a style as I possibly can.  That doesn't mean it will appeal to you.  I'm sure others will answer with mutating versions.

Comment: There are time's I suppose sketchy coding practices are required :) That's ok I didn't mind your comment. I do see value in your solution. For my requirements I need to update my data, but I can see this solution helping someone who is looking to do the above by creating a new data set.

Answer (score 0):

Hi check this function i made just now out its really short i think its really good i dont know what is a "recursion" but i tested this on a very nested array with objects and this also works with object i think take look at the output :)
EDIT: I FOUND A BETTER WAY THAT DOESN'T DELETE THE DATA BUT RETURNS A SORTED OBJ/OR ARRAY (you can pass either into this function to be sorted) pls give feedback

```js
var myData = [{
    "color": "green",
    "moreColors": [
        {
            "color": "blue"
        },
        {
            "color": "blue",
            "moreColor": [
                {
                    "color": "blue"
                },
                {
                    "color": "blue",
                    "moreColors": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},['blue'],"blue"]
function searchArrOrObj(objOrArray,color,newColor) {
    let arrayOrObj = Object.assign((objOrArray.constructor===Array?[]:{}), objOrArray)
    for (item in arrayOrObj) {
        if (arrayOrObj[item]===color) {
            arrayOrObj[item] = newColor;
        } else if (typeof arrayOrObj[item]==='object') {
            arrayOrObj[item] = searchArrOrObj(arrayOrObj[item],color,newColor)
        }
    } 
    return arrayOrObj;
}
let newData = searchArrOrObj(myData,"blue","red")
console.log(myData)
console.log(newData)
```