# How does one, within a nested data-structure of parent-objects and child-arrays, find a data-item by a specific (unique) key-value pair?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, data-structures

Given is a data-structure as follows ...

```
const tree = {
  name: "Documents",
  type: "dir",
  full: "/home/adityam/Documents",
  children: [{
    name: "file.txt",
    type: "file",
    full: "/home/adityam/Documents/file.txt",
  }, {
    name: "anotherFolder",
    type: "dir",
    full: "/home/adityam/Documents/anotherFolder",
    children: [],
  }],
};
```

... but object properties might change in value and vary by name (key) and count (amount of entries).

What's stable though, is the base data-structure with an object's/item's `full` property (string value) and the possible presence of a `children` property (array type, empty of not).

In order to later change a data-item's value one needs to first find/retrieve the former from the nested data-structure by e.g. an item's known `full` property value.

In case of an item like ...

```
{
  name: "anotherFolder",
  type: "dir",
  full: "/home/adityam/Documents/anotherFolder",
  children: [],
}
```

... where one wants to change e.g. `children`, the item first needs to be found/retrieved via its known `full` property value of `"/home/adityam/Documents/anotherFolder"`.

How would one achieve such a task?

Comment: Possibly of use? [Search a deeply nested array to update an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72093885/search-a-deeply-nested-array-to-update-an-object)

Comment: _"how do i do it?"_: by attempting something and when that attempt fails come back here, post your code as a [mcve], and we'll try and help you. What we can't do is debug code that doesn't exist.

Comment: Is at least the base fractal structure always the same ... `{ /* key value pairs , */ children: [  { /* key value pairs , */ children: [ /* ... */ ] } ] }`?

Comment: @PeterSeliger Apparently if `type` is `dir`, then the property `children` exists; if it is `file`, it does not.

Comment: @OskarGrosser ... It is not **"apparently"**, just **probably** / **likely** since the OP states (also just vaguely) ... _"this object might not be same on every user's computer because these are dynamically generated."_

Comment: yes, for file it doesn't exist.

Comment: First off, please takes Andy's comment to heart.  The requirements aren't quite clear to me.  If you're looking to mutate an existing object in the tree, one that you already have a reference to, then just mutate it through that reference and the tree will follow.  If you want to do this in a non-mutating manner with a value equivalent to the one in the tree, but not a reference, then you're going to need to tell us how you recognize the target value.  Or is it something in between?

Comment: every object in the object/array will always have a property `full` which is the absolute path of the element in the user's file system, and this `full` property is always unique

Comment: Is your problem finding the object, modifying the property, or both? If you're having trouble finding the object, see [pilchard's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72093885/search-a-deeply-nested-array-to-update-an-object).

Comment: With the OP's last comment I have the feeling that the OP's problem could be described best with ... _How does one, within a nested parent-object child-array data-structure, find a data-item by its `full` property value?_ @AdityaMishra ... Is that so?

Comment: yes @PeterSeliger

Comment: @AdityaMishra ... Then please change the title accordingly and edit the entire description section for more precision. Maybe the OP can now even come up with an own attempt since the entire matter is not that complex anymore except of a very manageable recursion approach.

Comment: i hope the title makes sense now @PeterSeliger Sorry For the mistake, english is not my native language, so it took me some time to write the question

Comment: If you already have the `element`, why do you need to search for it? Can't you just edit the children directly?

Comment: that is the thing, that element i have is somewhere inside the `tree` variable which i need to modify and not the element i have itself

Comment: Now that you updated your question it makes a lot more sense

Comment: @AdityaMishra ... From all the provided approaches are there any questions left?

Comment: @AdityaMishra ... an OP's disappearance without any feedback leaves at least me always a little disappointed, since I never know whether e.g. the OP could be helped or the OP did learn something. Sometimes just saying thanks helps to not experience repelled/denied help with the next tricky questions.

Comment: @AdityaMishra ... and [accepting one owns **non-answer** on barely half a follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72648522/modify-add-a-array-deeply-nested-inside-object/72676370#72676370), related to the subject here, is more than questionable.

Answer (score 1):

## Searching for the node

### Recursion!

You can find a reference for such a tree node with a [recursive](https://pages.di.unipi.it/marino/python/Recursion/TheThreeLawsofRecursion.html) (search) function:

> All recursive algorithms must obey three important laws:
>
> 1. A recursive algorithm must call itself, recursively.
> 2. A recursive algorithm must have a **base case**.
> 3. A recursive algorithm must change its state and move toward the base case.

For example `findNodeRecursive(name, node)`:

1. If property `full` of *node* equals *name*, return *node*. (**Base case**: Found)
2. If property `type` of *node* is not `"dir"`, return null. (**Base case**: Cannot be inside)
3. For each element *childNode* of property `children` of *node*: (Moving toward some base case)

   1. Let *result* be the result of the call `findNodeRecursive(name, childNode)`. (Recursive call)
   2. If *result* is not null, return *result*. (**Base case**: Found in `children`)
4. Return null. (**Base case**: Not found)

```js
// Implementation of the algorithm above
function findNodeRecursive(fullName, node) {
  if (node.full === fullName) return node;
  if (node.type !== "dir") return null;
  
  for (const childNode of node.children) {
    const result = findNodeRecursive(fullName, childNode);
    if (result !== null) return result;
  }
  
  return null;
}

const tree = {
  name: "Documents",
  type: "dir",
  full: "/home/adityam/Documents",
  children: [
    {
      name: "file.txt",
      type: "file",
      full: "/home/adityam/Documents/file.txt",
    },
    {
      name: "anotherFolder",
      type: "dir",
      full: "/home/adityam/Documents/anotherFolder",
      children: []
    }
  ]
};

console.log(findNodeRecursive("/home/adityam/Documents/anotherFolder", tree));
```

### Iteratively

There is also an iterative solution, which requires flattening the tree to a flat array, and then search for the node by its name.

Flattening can be done in multiple ways, either recursively again, or iteratively.

```js
function findNodeIterative(name, node) {
  const nodes = [node];
  
  // Iterative flattening
  for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
    if (nodes[i].children) nodes.push(...nodes[i].children);
  }
  
  return nodes.find(n => n.full === name);
}

const tree = {
  name: "Documents",
  type: "dir",
  full: "/home/adityam/Documents",
  children: [
    {
      name: "file.txt",
      type: "file",
      full: "/home/adityam/Documents/file.txt",
    },
    {
      name: "anotherFolder",
      type: "dir",
      full: "/home/adityam/Documents/anotherFolder",
      children: []
    }
  ]
};

console.log(findNodeIterative("/home/adityam/Documents/anotherFolder", tree));
```

## Modifying `children`

The value of `children` is an array. If you want to modify *this* array, you can use one of its mutating methods, for example [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```js
// Reference found with some function, for example the above findByName()
const node = {
  name: "anotherFolder",
  type: "dir",
  full: "/home/adityam/Documents/anotherFolder",
  children: []
};

const nodesToAdd = [
  {
    name: "someFile.txt",
    type: "file",
    full: "/home/adityam/Documents/anotherFolder/someFile.txt"
  },
  {
    name: "someFolder",
    type: "dir",
    full: "/home/adityam/Documents/anotherFolder/someFolder",
    children: []
  }
];

console.log("Before modifying:\nNode:", node);
node.children.splice(0, 0, ...nodesToAdd);
console.log("After modifying:\nNode:", node);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:unset!important;top:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP's actual use case seems to be finding an array's data-item within a nested data-structure of unknown depth of the form ...

```
{
  /* data-item or root-object/node */
  additionalKey: "value-pair(s)",
  children: [{
    /* data-item */
    additionalKey: "value-pair(s)",
    children: [
      /* optional and possibly empty `children` array */
    ],
  }],
}
```

... in order to later manipulate the returned matching sub-data-structure. The current use case is to find such an item based on any item's unique key-value pair of the `full` property.

Though this can be done very easily with a recursive approach, the hereby provided generic implementation allows searching by a to be passed configuration which allows custom values for a data-structure's child-array name (here ... `{ arrKey: 'children' }`) and of a `props` property which either partially or fully covers a to be matched item's properties/entries signature (here, e.g. ... `{ full: '/home/adityam/Documents/file.txt' }` or even `{ name: 'Documents', type: 'dir' }` ).

The find function itself is implemented in a way that it accepts any `type` as 1st argument and the `finder` configuration as its 2nd. If the first argument was an array-type then its [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method is going to execute the implemented find function self-recursively. For any other `object` type (except the `null` value) an `if` clause iterates over the provided `props`' [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) in order to assure that [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) of the `props`' key-value pairs has a matching counterpart in the passed and currently processed `type` (the function's first passed argument). In case the current sub-data-item's `type` does not match, another self recursion takes place; this time with a possible present child array which gets accessed via the currently processed type and the configuration's `arrKey` value.

As soon as a match got found the configuration which is passed with every recursion gets assigned the matching sub-structure's reference as `finder.match`. The latter also serves as the recursive find function's only return value which also makes sure that an array's `find` process will exit early.

```js
function recursivelyFindArrayItemByProperties(type, finder) {
  const { arrKey, props } = finder;

  if (Array.isArray(type)) {
    type
      // find will exit early.
      .find(item =>
        !!recursivelyFindArrayItemByProperties(item, finder)
      );
  } else if (type && ('object' === typeof type)) {
    if (
      Object
        .entries(props)
        .every(([key, value]) => type[key] === value)
    ) {
      finder.match = type;
    } else {
      recursivelyFindArrayItemByProperties(type[arrKey], finder);
    }    
  }
  return finder.match;
}

const tree = {
  name: "Documents",
  type: "dir",
  full: "/home/adityam/Documents",
  children: [{
    name: "file.txt",
    type: "file",
    full: "/home/adityam/Documents/file.txt",
  }, {
    name: "anotherFolder",
    type: "dir",
    full: "/home/adityam/Documents/anotherFolder",
    children: [{
      name: "fooBar.txt",
      type: "file",
      full: "/home/adityam/Documents/fooBar.txt",
    }, {
      name: "bazBiz.txt",
      type: "file",
      full: "/home/adityam/Documents/bazBiz.txt",
    }],
  }],
};

console.log(
  'found by ... { full: "/home/adityam/Documents/fooBar.txt" } ... ',
  recursivelyFindArrayItemByProperties(tree, {
    arrKey: 'children',
    props: {
      full: "/home/adityam/Documents/fooBar.txt",
    },
  })
);
console.log(
  'found by ... { full: "/home/adityam/Documents/bazBiz.txt" } ... ',
  recursivelyFindArrayItemByProperties(tree, {
    arrKey: 'children',
    props: {
      full: "/home/adityam/Documents/bazBiz.txt",
    },
  })
);

console.log(
  '\nfound by ... { full: "/home/adityam/Documents/file.txt" } ... ',
  recursivelyFindArrayItemByProperties(tree, {
    arrKey: 'children',
    props: {
      full: "/home/adityam/Documents/file.txt",
    },
  })
);

console.log(
  '\nfound by ... { full: "/home/adityam/Documents/anotherFolder" } ... ',
  recursivelyFindArrayItemByProperties(tree, {
    arrKey: 'children',
    props: {
      full: "/home/adityam/Documents/anotherFolder",
    },
  })
);
console.log(
  'found by ... { full: "/home/adityam/Documents" } ... ',
  recursivelyFindArrayItemByProperties(tree, {
    arrKey: 'children',
    props: {
      full: "/home/adityam/Documents",
    },
  })
);

console.log(
  '\nfound by ... { name: "anotherFolder", type: "dir" } ... ',
  recursivelyFindArrayItemByProperties(tree, {
    arrKey: 'children',
    props: {
      name: "anotherFolder",
      type: "dir",
      // full: "/home/adityam/Documents/anotherFolder",
    },
  })
);
console.log(
  'found by ... { name: "Documents", type: "dir" } ... ',
  recursivelyFindArrayItemByProperties(tree, {
    arrKey: 'children',
    props: {
      name: "Documents",
      type: "dir",
      // full: "/home/adityam/Documents",
    },
  })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Knowing all this, one of cause now could refactor the current `find` implementation which returns a single, namely the very first matching sub-structure's, reference into a `match` solution which recursively collects any matching sub-structure's reference.

```js
function recursivelyMatchArrayItemsByProperties(type, finder) {
  const { arrKey, props } = finder;

  if (Array.isArray(type)) {
    type
      .filter(item =>
        !!recursivelyMatchArrayItemsByProperties(item, finder)
      );
  } else if (type && ('object' === typeof type)) {
    if (
      Object
        .entries(props)
        .every(([key, value]) => type[key] === value)
    ) {
      (finder.matches ??= []).push(type);
    } else {
      recursivelyMatchArrayItemsByProperties(type[arrKey], finder);
    }    
  }
  return finder.matches;
}

const tree = {
  name: "Documents",
  type: "dir",
  full: "/home/adityam/Documents",
  children: [{
    name: "file.txt",
    type: "file",
    full: "/home/adityam/Documents/file.txt",
  }, {
    name: "anotherFolder",
    type: "dir",
    full: "/home/adityam/Documents/anotherFolder",
    children: [{
      name: "fooBar.txt",
      type: "file",
      full: "/home/adityam/Documents/fooBar.txt",
    }, {
      name: "bazBiz.txt",
      type: "file",
      full: "/home/adityam/Documents/bazBiz.txt",
    }],
  }],
};

console.log(
  'matches by ... { full: "/home/adityam/Documents/fooBar.txt" } ... ',
  recursivelyMatchArrayItemsByProperties(tree, {
    arrKey: 'children',
    props: {
      full: "/home/adityam/Documents/fooBar.txt",
    },
  })
);
console.log(
  'matches by ... { type: "file" } ... ',
  recursivelyMatchArrayItemsByProperties(tree, {
    arrKey: 'children',
    props: {
      type: "file",
    },
  })
);
console.log(
  'matches by ... { type: "dir" } ... ',
  recursivelyMatchArrayItemsByProperties(tree, {
    arrKey: 'children',
    props: {
      type: "dir",
    },
  })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I know that you're not finished with this answer, but it looks to me like your partial object matcher (in the first `else` clause) will only match scalar properties, and only in the root.  That's not necessarily a bad thing, but the restriction should be noted.

Comment: I'll have to read it more carefully when I have time.  It looked to me like it couldn't be used to match, say, `{path: '/foo/bar/baz', stats: {size: 1234, access: '0644'}}`, because `stats` is an object and not a scalar value.  But I'll take a look again later.

Comment: @ScottSauyet ... ahh, now I understood. You're right, `props` has to be a scalar. But I think this is already a more generic solution than what the OP actually needs.

Comment: Yes, and mine is still more generic... but when you go generic in these ways, you also leave more for the user to do.  They have to do a bit more to use yours than originally expected, and to use mine, they have to do still more.  In mine, the user has to write a generic predicate to check for matches, instead of your simple object, and has to write the function that does the modification yourself.  Of course I partially preconfigure those for the more specific solution.  But it's interesting to see the responses as a ladder of abstraction.

Comment: You've nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already answered, I will post the answer that I wrote earlier, but would usually not post until the OP showed an attempt.

---

I think we're best off breaking apart the tree navigation code from the code that checks if we're at the right node and from the code that modifies a node.

Since I don't know what sort of modification you are interested in performing, I just add a `notice` property to the object, but you can use any function that returns a new version of the object, whether an altered clone, a reference to a mutated original, or something else entirely.  Here's an example:

```js
const modifyNode = (pred, fn) => (node, _, __,
  {children = [], ...rest} = node, 
  kids = children .map (modifyNode (pred, fn))
) => pred (node)
  ? fn (node)
  : {...rest, ...(kids .length ? {children: kids} : {})}

const modifyByPath = (path) => modifyNode (
  (node) => node.full === path, 
  (node) => ({...node, notice: '*** this was modified ***'})
)


var tree = {name: "Documents", type: "dir", full: "/home/adityam/Documents", children: [{name: "file.txt", type: "file", full: "/home/adityam/Documents/file.txt", }, {name: "anotherFolder", type: "dir",full: "/home/adityam/Documents/anotherFolder", children: [/* ... */]}]}

console .log (modifyByPath ('/home/adityam/Documents/anotherFolder') (tree))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We have a utility function `modifyNode` that accepts a predicate function to test whether we've hit the right node and a modification function that takes a node and returns a node, replaced or altered as desired.  It returns a function that takes a node recursively configured with `children` arrays of objects (themselves with the same structure) and returns an altered version of your tree with every matching node replaced with the result of calling your modification function.

Our main function, `modifyByPath`, accepts a full path name and calls `modifyNode` with a simple test predicate and a dummy modification function, which returns a function that does our main work.  We will call it like `modifyByPath (path) (tree)`.