# Obtain values fron nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, concatenation, reduce, flatmap, flat

I have the fallowing data structure:

```
products = [
    {
        name: 'Menu1',
            subitems: [
                {
                    name: 'Menu2'
                },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Menu3',
            subitems: [
                {
                    name: 'Menu4',
                    subitems: [
                        {
                            name:'Menu5'
                        },
                        {
                            name:'Menu6'
                        }
                    ]
                },
        ]
    },
]
```

Want to obtain all the names values inside of it, no matter how deep nested it is. I 've tried solutions related to flat, reduce, concat, map, for of, etc but I never get the deepest level 'Menu5' and 'Menu6'

I think this is saying recursivity out loud but I can't implement it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all values by specific key in a deep nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54857222/find-all-values-by-specific-key-in-a-deep-nested-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const _getNames = (products = []) =>
  products.reduce((names, { name, subitems = [] }) => {
    names.push(name);
    if(subitems.length > 0) {
      names.push(..._getNames(subitems));
    }
    return names;
  }, []);

const products = [
  { 
    name: 'Menu1',
    subitems: [ 
      { name: 'Menu2' } 
    ] 
  },
  { 
    name: 'Menu3', 
    subitems: [ 
      { name: 'Menu4', 
        subitems: [ 
          { name:'Menu5' }, { name:'Menu6' } 
        ] 
      }
    ]
  }
];
console.log( _getNames(products) );
```

Comment: Marked it, and checked that works for all  cases. Do you how to do it also with lodash? Where to read to master the reducer technique?

Comment: I believe it's similar in lodash: `_.reduce(products, (names, { name, subitems = [] }) => {...}, [])`. I've linked the docs in the answer.